# Robocopy for Microsoft Access Files MIR switch

Tags: backup, robocopy, microsoft-access

We are using robocopy with MIR switch to backup our Microsoft Access Databases, i.e., .accdb, and .mdb files. Interesting thing with Access database files is that you can open a database, add a few records into  a table, close the db and the size of the database file will not change.
Will robocopy know that he has to copy this file next time when he does the backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the file not necessarily leads to a change in the file's size, but typically (i.e. unless a sufficiently privileged process has changed that) the following always happens:

- the *"last modified"* timestamp of the file is updated to the current timestamp
- the *"archive"* bit is touched (if it was not set, it is set by the OS automatically)

Robocopy would compare the "last modified" timestamp of the destination with that of the source and copy when these two differ (this behavior might be tweaked according to your requirements using the `/xn` and `/xo` switches). Robocopy would only honor (and reset) the `archive` file attribute when you use `/m` switch - see the [robocopy documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for details.